# Pojo classes to serialize to json

Tags: java, json

I want to display my Json response as below. Below are my classes. Class name (transaction_status) should not come in json response, is their any way we can achieve this any suggestion experts ?

```
//Expected json response
{
    "view": {
        "payment_transaction": [
            {

                "status": "Delivered",   
                "reason": "XXX",        
                "event": [
                    {
                           "status": "Delivered",  
                           "reason": "XXX" 
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

// but it is coming as below 
{
    "view": {
        "payment_transaction": [
            {

                "status": "Delivered",   // 1)Coming correctly
                "reason": "XXX",         // 2)Coming correctly 
                "event": [
                    {
                        "transaction_status": { // don't want to this field to come
                            "status": "Delivered",  
                            "reason": "XXX" 
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

public class View {
    public static class PaymentExternalView {

     @SerializedName("status")
     private String transactionStatus;

     @SerializedName("reason")
     private String transactionStatusReason;

     private transient TransactionStatus tranStatus;

     public TransactionStatus getTranStatus() {
           return tranStatus;
     }

     public void setTranStatus(TransactionStatus tranStatus) {
           this.tranStatus = tranStatus;
     }

     public String getTransactionStatus() {  
           this.transactionStatus = tranStatus.getStatus().toString();
           return transactionStatus;
     }

     public void setTransactionStatus(String transactionStatus) {
           this.transactionStatus = transactionStatus;
     }

     public String getTransactionStatusReason() {
           this.transactionStatusReason = tranStatus.getReason().toString();
           return transactionStatusReason;
     }

     public void setTransactionStatusReason(String transactionStatusReason) {
           this.transactionStatusReason = transactionStatusReason;
     }

   }

    public static class Event {

    private TransactionStatus transactionStatus;

    //@SerializedName("status")       // If I specify these variables error is coming as Multiple json fileds 
    //private String transactionStatus;

    //@SerializedName("reason")
    //private String transactionStatusReason;


    public TransactionStatus getTransactionStatus() {
        this.transactionStatus = tranStatus.t
        return transactionStatus;
     }

     public void setTransactionStatus(TransactionStatus status) {
       this.transactionStatus = status;
     }
     /**
     public String getTransactionStatus() {
           this.transactionStatus = tranStatus.getStatus().toString();
           return transactionStatus;
     }

     public void setTransactionStatus(String transactionStatus) {
           this.transactionStatus = transactionStatus;
     }

     public String getTransactionStatusReason() {
           this.transactionStatusReason = tranStatus.getReason().toString();
           return transactionStatusReason;
     }

     public void setTransactionStatusReason(String transactionStatusReason) {
           this.transactionStatusReason = transactionStatusReason;
     }
     **/
    }
}


public class TransactionStatus {
  private String status;

  private String reason;

  public String getStatus() {
     return status;
  }
  public void setStatus(String status) {
     this.status = status;
  }
  public String getReason() {
     return reason;
  }
  public void setReason(String reason) {
     this.reason = reason;
  }
}
```

I cannot modify my TransactionStatus class as this used in many other places. In Event class if I tried to set @SerializedName("status") and @SerializedName("reason") error is coming as Multiple json fields. I  want to display my status and reason one level up i.e want to get rid of "transaction_status" tag in json response.

Comment: Please update your question with pojo classes and code where you seralize to json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using gson... try with a custom serializer for PaymentExternalView (class containing TransactionStatus member) class.

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

JsonSerializer<PaymentExternalView> serializer = ...;  
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(PaymentExternalView.class, serializer);

Gson customGson = gsonBuilder.create();  
String customJSON = customGson.toJson(value);
```

Then create json as desired...

```
JsonSerializer<PaymentExternalView> serializer = new JsonSerializer<>() {  
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(PaymentExternalView src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        // ...
        json.addProperty("status", src.getTransactionStatus().getStatus());
        json.addProperty("reason", src.getTransactionStatus().getReason());

        return json;
    }
};
```

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-serialization-part-1

Comment: Thanks @Marc Ströbel